# Extract a specific value from a text file

Tags: python, text, printing, extract

Total newbie here. I have a `.txt` file and I want to extract a specific value....

The `.txt` file is structure like this:

```
{
"animal": "Cat",
"colour": "golden",
...and so on
}
```

I can open and print he whole file ...... but how do I print just the `"animal"` plus its value which in this case is `"cat"` bit?

The file itself has hundreds of entries and I want to know how to extract and print all the `"animal"`s for example.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The text file seems to be a valid JSON file. If it's the case, you can use `json` module to get a dictionary from this file.

Comment: do you have single `{ "animal": ... }` or list `[ {"animal":... }, {"animal":... }, ...]` . Both would need to use module `json` to load it and convert to Python list, And later first will need only ["animal"] but second will need `for item in data: item["animal"]`

Comment: do you have file with `[ ]` or without `[ ]` in `[ {"animal":... }, {"animal":... }, ...]` ? It may need to add `[ ]` to create correct JSON data and use module `json`

Answer (score 0):

The text file you provided seems to be a dictionary itself. So I suggest you use `ast` module in order to change the format of this text file from string to a valid dictionary and then call *animal* key from this dictionary:

```py
import ast
with open("myText.txt") as f:
  myFile = f.read()
  myDict = ast.literal_eval(myFile)
  print(myDict["animal"])
```

##### Output

```
Cat
```

Note that, I have named the text file `myText.txt`. It might be different in your machine, so change it to the valid path of your text file.

Comment: OP mentioned `all the "animal"` - maybe OP has list `[ {"animal":... }, {"animal":... }, ...]` and it would need to add `for`-loop to your code. But OP doesn't say if they are in `[ ]` and it would need to add `[]` to create correct JSON data.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help..... your code does work. My file is actually a JSON file but I can apply what you have shown me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `"animal": ...` in separated lines then you could read line by line and check `if "animal" in line` and later `split(":")` and remove `" ",` to get only text `Cat`, etc.

Minimal working example. I use `io` only to simulate file but you should use `open()`

```
text = '''{
"animal": "Cat",
"colour": "golden",
#...and so on
}
{
"animal": "Dog",
"colour": "black",
#...and so on
}
'''

import io

#f = open(filename)
f = io.StringIO(text)

for line in f:
    line = line.strip(' \n,')  # remove spaces, tabs but also `,`
    
    #if 'animal' in line:            # it get `animal` in any place - ie. 'small animals'
    if line.startswith('"animal"'):  # it get only "animal" (with `" "`) at the beginning of line
        parts = line.split(':')
        print(parts[1].strip(' "'))
```

Result:

```
Cat
Dog
```

But this way you get only value for `animal` and you would need much more code to get all values in records - so it would need more code to display `colour` only for `Cat`.

---

But your data looks similar to JSON so maybe you have all records inside `[ ]` and with `,` between records - like

```
[
{
"animal": "Cat",
"colour": "golden",
#...and so on
},
{
"animal": "Dog",
"colour": "black",
#...and so on
}
]
```

and then you could use module `json` to get it as list with dictionares and use `for`-loop to check every record and get `animal`. And it could be simpler to get other values - ie. get `colour` only for `Cat`.

```
text = '''[
{
"animal": "Cat",
"colour": "golden"
},
{
"animal": "Dog",
"colour": "black"
}
]
'''

import io
import json

#f = open(filename)
f = io.StringIO(text)

data = json.load(f)

for record in data:
    print(record['animal'])
    if record['animal'] == 'Cat':
        print('  colour:', record['colour'])
```

Result:

```
Cat
  colour: golden
Dog
```

---

If you create this file with records then you could use module `json` to write data.

Comment: Thanks furas, yes it is a JSON file....
So far I've done this:
removed these 2 lines so I just get the 'animals' returned.
    if record['animal'] == 'Cat':
        print('  colour:', record['colour'])

My next  step was to read from the JSON file on my desktop so I now have:
f = open('/Users/me/Desktop/directoryA/animal.json')
f = io.StringIO(text)
data = json.load(f)
for record in data:
    print(record['animal'])

but I get this
Redeclared 'f' defined above without usage
and, if I comment 'f = io.StringIO(text)' out I get a different error

Any ideas?
thanks.....

Comment: it seems I fogot to wrie that I use `io` only to simulate file - so everyone can simply copy and run it - but you have to use only `f = open(...)`. And I have no idea what is your other error - you would have to add this in question (you will have more space and it will be more readable). Maybe you don't have correctly formatted JSON, maybe you addded records `{..}` without `[ , ]` and now you have broken JSON - or something similar to multiJSON (many JSON in one file). And if you create this file then this may need to change code which you use to write data.